# Spring - Hibernate - List display error: java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "luce"

Tags: java, hibernate, jsp, spring-mvc

Good morning all.

I have a problem with a `NumberFormatException` while rendering my JSP page.

I have a model which has a ManyToOne annotation with another model

Illuminazione.java (ManyToOne relation with `Luce.java`)

```
// showing only the interesting part
@ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "id_luce")
    public Luce getLuce() {
        return this.luce;
    }

    public void setLuce(Luce luce) {
        this.luce = luce;
    }
```

In my controller I have to show a result of a Join query and I cannot do it with Hibernate Criteria (at least, it's out of my skills...)

This is the method in the controller

```
@RequestMapping(value = {path+"/illuminazione"}, method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String lightsSituation(ModelMap model){
    List <Illuminazione> illuminazione = illuminazioneService.showLightsSituation();
    model.addAttribute("illuminazione", illuminazione);
    return path+"/illuminazione";
}
```

and `showLightsSituation` in the service class come from the correspondent DAO implementation which is:

```
public List<Illuminazione> showLightsSituations() {

        String query = "select `id_luce`, `isLit`, `date_time` from illuminazione i inner join ";
        query += "(SELECT `id_luce` as numeroLuce2, max(date_time) as MaxDate from illuminazione group by `id_luce`)";
        query += "ill on i.`id_luce`=ill.`numeroLuce2` and i.`date_time` = ill.MaxDate order by i.`id_luce` asc";

        @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
        List <Illuminazione> lista = getSession().createSQLQuery(query).list();

        return lista;
    }
```

Now, in my illuminazione.jsp, i want to display the values of the Illuminazione object and also the linked from Luce, in this way

```
<c:forEach items="${illuminazione}" var="ill">
        <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><div class="list-field">${ill.luce.numeroLuce}</div></td>
            <td><div class="list-field">${ill.luce.nomeLuce}</div></td>
            <td><div class="list-field">${ill.isLit}</div></td>
            <td><div class="list-field">${ill.dateTime}</div></td>

            <td class="actions"><a class="pull-right" href="<c:url value='/lights/${ill.idEvento}' />"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-edit"></span></a></td>
        </tr>
        </c:forEach>
```

where `numeroLuce` and `nomeLuce` are the fields from Luce.java which are linked to Illuminazione.java.

I'm getting this exception

```
org.apache.jasper.JasperException: An exception occurred processing JSP page /WEB-INF/pages/lights/illuminazione.jsp at line 115

112:         <c:forEach items="${illuminazione}" var="ill">
113:         <tbody>
114:         <tr>
115:             <td><div class="list-field">${ill.luce.numeroLuce}</div></td>
116:             <td><div class="list-field">${ill.luce.nomeLuce}</div></td>
117:             <td><div class="list-field">${ill.isLit}</div></td>
118:             <td><div class="list-field">${ill.dateTime}</div></td>
```

caused by

```
java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "luce"
    java.lang.NumberFormatException.forInputString(NumberFormatException.java:65)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:580)
    java.lang.Integer.parseInt(Integer.java:615)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.coerce(ArrayELResolver.java:151)
    javax.el.ArrayELResolver.getValue(ArrayELResolver.java:64)
    ....
    ....
```

The problem is that I can try to iterate in the view with the indexes of the List in this way `${ill[1]}` and so on, but how to manage the MayToOne relation?

Thanks

Comment: What is the type of your column numeroLuce in database? I think it's varchar and you are mapping it on java as numeric!

Comment: It's an int... I already use it in other controllers and views...